# Cannot boot after BIOS update

Tags: bios

After BIOS update:

a) BIOS doesn't save any changes, apart from time and date

b) BIOS doesn't see the internal hard drive, but sees USB drives.

What I had before:
* I had TPM initialized and active
* Secure Boot to Windows 10 with bitlocker
* Supervisor password on BIOS

Specs:
* AMI BIOS (Aptio 5, apparently) 
* i7-5500u, NEC-built/Lenovo-branded laptop (Lenovo Lavie Z)

Issue started after:
I did a bios update, but (not sure if anything of this has contributed to problems)
* didn't turn off bitlocker and secure boot
* accidentally only reflashed the main block

Symptoms of the issue:

- BIOS is reset (expected)
- TPM Support is showing as Enabled, TPM state is Disabled&Deactivated.
- Boot: Legacy mode (was UEFI), Hard disk is showing as question marks
- No changes are saved, apart from date and time.

What I tried to fix:

- reflashing under win (recovery drive) and dos; all resulted in "43: Error -- problem erasing flash" regardless of the bios ROM i'm using
- attempted to do the "emergency USB recovery" by pressing Win+B, Control+Home, Home, Fn+R, Fn+B (both on internal and on external keyboard) when powering up and putting the ROM as original filename (763A0400.ROM) or AMIBOOT.ROM. Never worked.
- Disconnecting the battery and CMOS battery did reset system time, but hasn't fixed anything.

*** EDIT ***
This is what I'm getting when trying to reflash:

```
c:\LV\FLASH\nz2uj02w>AFUWINx64.EXE 763A0800.ROM /p /n /b
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------    +
|                 AMI Firmware Update Utility  v5.06.00                             |
|      Copyright (C)2014 American Megatrends Inc. All Rights Reserved.      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 Reading flash ............... done
 Secure Flash enabled, recalculate ROM size with signature...
 - FFS checksums ......... ok
 Loading capsule to secure memory buffer ... done
43 - Error: Problem erasing flash.0520000 (0%)



c:\LV\FLASH\nz2uj02w>AFUWINx64.EXE 763A0800.ROM /capsule
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------    +
|                 AMI Firmware Update Utility  v5.06.00                         |
|      Copyright (C)2014 American Megatrends Inc. All Rights Reserved.      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 Reading flash ............... done
 - FFS checksums ......... ok
18 - Error: Secure Flash Rom Verify fail.
```

With /GAN option, flashing reports success, but nothing is changed and BIOS Version is unaffected.

```
c:\LV\FLASH\nz2uj02w>AFUWINx64.EXE 763A0800.ROM /gan
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                 AMI Firmware Update Utility  v5.06.00                         |
|      Copyright (C)2014 American Megatrends Inc. All Rights Reserved.      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 Reading flash ............... done
 Erasing All Block ............ done
 Updating All Block ........... done
 Verifying All Block .......... done
```

[image: Bios-1]
[image: Bios-2]
[image: Bios-3]

Comment: What does it say under HDD BBS priorities? Do you have another hard disk to test the system booting?

Comment: I would assume that the bios is fine for the moment and that "updating the bios without suspending bitlocker" is the one problem you have.  It is possible that the bios would start saving settings , if you Defaulted the bios first (after bios changes), then re-post back into the bios, then make all your bios changes back the way they were (after flashing).  The bitlocker "recovery" then I dont know anything about, other than there is a process required to get that drive re-recognised now.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas only lists 1 device with question marks: https://goo.gl/photos/7hXMKyfe8WKk7cAg8. Testing another drive is actually a good idea, will give it a shot!

Comment: @Psycogeek as I understand, expected behavior for updating bios with bitlocker is to get a recovery screen, which I can handle (luckily I have all the codes). Are you suggesting to do the factory reset to the BIOS (F9)? I did try that, doesn't help either.

Comment: Attempting to boot with another disk, or going into bios without disk, didn't change anything.

Comment: Yea that is what I meant. what did this mean "accidentally only reflashed the main block"   ?